# Как обрабатывать изображение экрана в реальном времени, по сути делать видео захват экрана

Tags: python-3.x

Мне нужно получать изображение с экрана монитора причём чтобы  изображение обновлялось в реальном времени, (потом я буду искать заданное изображение(объект),поиск я уже реализовал). Как это можно сделать на питоне 3.x,с помощью каких библиотек?

код по поиску:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("screen0.png")  #работает только с 1 картинкой
imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread("stone.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

result = cv2.matchTemplate(imgg, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
loc = np.where(result >= 0.5)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
```

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&client=opera&hs=whQ&ei=zdEtXYneCcLZwQKqjaxI&q=pil+opencv+screenshot+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=pil+opencv+screenshot+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Тут есть объяснение для питона 2 версии,а мне надо для 3-ей

Comment: А FPS имеет значение?

Comment: без разницы,в данный момент но на будущее чем больше тем лучше(ну сам понимаешь (это только если можно в данный момент без разницы)

Comment: а в чем разница?

Comment: в синтаксисе если ты про разница между питоном 3 и 2

Comment: В первом варианте только одно изображение просто копировалось и записывалось под разными названиями а теперь реально видео захват)

Comment: А я думал мне комментарий был адресован

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
import numpy
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2


class Main:
    def __init__(self):

        self.template = cv2.imread("template.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        self.width, self.height = self.template.shape[::-1]

    def run(self):
        while True:

            sleep(1)

            array = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(ImageGrab.grab()), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            screen_shot_gray = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            result = cv2.matchTemplate(screen_shot_gray, self.template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

            loc = numpy.where(result >= 0.5)

            for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                cv2.rectangle(array, pt, (pt[0] + width, pt[1] + height), (0, 255, 0), 1)

            print(result)
            # Здесь добавляете код pyautogui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.run()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96352/discussion-on-answer-by-------).